# Tried to run Redis-Developer's Chat App Repository but contracted with errno: -3008

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, redis, socket.io

I have cloned repo [https://github.com/redis-developer/basic-redis-chat-app-demo-nodejs.git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijAIR.png) to learn about realtime chat app. But while running it locally in my machine it contracts with the error which is attached here

[image]

I also don't know where to get the values of:

```
REDIS_ENDPOINT_URL = "Redis server URI"
REDIS_PASSWORD = "Password to the server"
```

in order to run the app locally.
I just need to know how and where can I get these values so that I could run the app locally.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run that demo app you need to have a running Redis server. You can easily run in your local development machine using docker:

```
docker run --name redis-dev -d redis
```

You can skip setting those env variables if you are running the Redis locally on the default port, as it's set in the demo app:
https://github.com/redis-developer/basic-redis-chat-app-demo-nodejs/blob/15e2e8cd06ea8981b82186707549dd09eaed088e/server/redis.js#L5